# Java applet stretched after switching tab

Tags: java, layout, applet

So basically, my java applet gets stretchy after switching to another tab of your browser and back. Everything gets out of form and zoomed hard.
you can reproduce it like this:

1. http://abirechner.bplaced.net/
2. Fill in every textfield with a number from 1-15
3. Press "weitere Fächer"
4. Press "ok"
5. Fill in the first two lines with numbers from 1-15
6. Press "Prüfungsfächer"
7. Choose in the comboboxes "Deutsch", "Englisch", Geschichte, "Mathematik", or "Musik"
8. Fill in the textboxes with numbers from 1-15.
9. Press "auswerten"
10. Switch tab and go back.

It is a calculator for German a-levels, made as a school-project.

The layout uses BorderLayout with two Gridlayouts, that contain several Gridlayouts as well.

//EDIT: screenshot: http://picturepush.com/public/11206621

Comment: It would be really hard to fix it without seeing the code.

Comment: Also, considering adding screen shots to your question.

Comment: 1) I think something different was supposed to happen after step 4, since I never saw a `Prüfungsfächer` control. 2) Yes that applet rendering is messed up.  Does it do custom painting?  Does it mix AWT and Swing components? ..